# Copy an associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I've the following piece of code for copying one associative array to other,

```
<script>

    var some_db = new Array();

    some_db["One"] = "1";

    some_db["Two"] = "2";

    some_db["Three"] = "3";

    var copy_db = new Array();

    alert(some_db["One"]);

    copy_db = some_db.slice();

    alert(copy_db["One"]);

</script>
```

But the second alert says "undefined".. Am I doing something wrong here? Any pointers please...

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javascript.

Comment: JavaScript arrays don't work with non-numerical keys. That's why `.slice` does not pick them up. Use a plain object instead and then look at [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

Comment: @Niko: Arrays are objects from the beginning... they are not "turned".

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I missed that. Corrected my comment.

Comment: @Peter - You really should accept some answers on your questions before asking more of them.

Comment: Thanks folks for the reply. I've changed my code to Object and is working fine now..

@gnarf Sorry was not aware of +1 here. Will take care from now on :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JavaScript, associative arrays are called objects.

```
<script>
    var some_db = {
       "One" : "1",
       "Two" : "2",
       "Three" : "3"
    };

    var copy_db = clone(some_db);

    alert(some_db["One"]);

    alert(copy_db["One"]);

    function clone(obj) {
        if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
        var copy = obj.constructor();
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }
</script>
```

I would normally use `var copy_db = $.extend({}, some_db);` if I was using jQuery.

**Fiddle Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/RNF5T/

[Thanks @maja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270711/copy-associative-array-in-javascript#comment30343215_10270781).

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks duh. Fixed.

Comment: Notice, that the function does not copy child-objects

Comment: @iambriansreed No, it does not. You would need to call your clone-Function again, when assigning an attribute.  See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85Gbr/   This would perform a deep-copy: http://jsfiddle.net/RNF5T/

Comment: @maja - Good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

As @Niko says in the comment, there aren't any associative arrays in JavaScript.

You are actually setting properties on the array object, which is not a very good idea.  You would be better off using an actual object.

```
var some_db = {};
some_db["One"] = "1";
some_db["Two"] = "2";
some_db["Three"] = "3";

var copy_db = {}, prop;
// Loop over all the keys in the object
for (prop in some_db) {
  // Make sure the object has this value, and not its prototype
  if (some_db.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    copy_db[prop] = some_db[prop];
  }
}
```

Many libraries implement an `extend` function which does exactly this (copy keys from one object to another). Most notably [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend) and [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend). Underscore.js also has [`_.clone(obj)`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#clone) which is effectively `_.extend( {}, obj )`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use JSON, you can take this 'associative array' object:

```
var assArray = {zero:0, one:1, two:2, three:3, what:'ever', you:'want'};
```

And 'clone' it like this:

```
var clonedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(assArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) could help. It performs a shallow copy to the dictionary object or array.

```
var some_db = {
  "One" : "1",
  "Two" : "2",
  "Three" : "3"
};

copy_db = _.clone(some_db);
```